# Correios - PLP XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-service

Na web service dos Correios existe um processo de envio de plp (pré-lista de postagem), que contem informações dos objetos postais. Estou enviando essa plp 
pelo método `fechaPlpVariosServicos`. Mas quando o cliente vai até a agencia, essa plp dá o seguinte erro no sistema Sara:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O xml é o seguinte:

```xml
<correioslog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <tipo_arquivo>Postagem</tipo_arquivo>
  <versao_arquivo>2.3</versao_arquivo>
  <plp>
    <id_plp />
    <valor_global />
    <mcu_unidade_postagem />
    <nome_unidade_postagem />
    <cartao_postagem>*********</cartao_postagem>
  </plp>
  <remetente>
    <numero_contrato>**********</numero_contrato>
    <numero_diretoria>75</numero_diretoria>
    <codigo_administrativo>**********</codigo_administrativo>
    <nome_remetente>Empresa Teste</nome_remetente>
    <logradouro_remetente>Rua Henri Dunant</logradouro_remetente>
    <numero_remetente>**** </numero_remetente>
    <complemento_remetente>Cj. 1301 &amp;amp; 1303 </complemento_remetente>
    <bairro_remetente>Morumbi</bairro_remetente>
    <cep_remetente>*******</cep_remetente>
    <cidade_remetente>SAO PAULO</cidade_remetente>
    <uf_remetente>SP</uf_remetente>
    <telefone_remetente>99999999</telefone_remetente>
    <fax_remetente>0</fax_remetente>
    <email_remetente>fulano@mail.net</email_remetente>
  </remetente>
  <forma_pagamento />
  <objeto_postal>
    <numero_etiqueta>DW009688975BR</numero_etiqueta>
    <codigo_objeto_cliente />
    <codigo_servico_postagem>40096</codigo_servico_postagem>
    <cubagem>0</cubagem>
    <peso>5500</peso>
    <rt1 />
    <rt2 />
    <destinatario>
      <nome_destinatario>Fulano</nome_destinatario>
      <telefone_destinatario>11984924498</telefone_destinatario>
      <celular_destinatario>11984924498</celular_destinatario>
      <email_destinatario>fulano@mail.com.br</email_destinatario>
      <logradouro_destinatario>Endereco fulano</logradouro_destinatario>
      <complemento_destinatario />
      <numero_end_destinatario>535</numero_end_destinatario>
    </destinatario>
    <nacional>
      <bairro_destinatario>CENTRO</bairro_destinatario>
      <cidade_destinatario>DIADEMA</cidade_destinatario>
      <uf_destinatario>SP</uf_destinatario>
      <cep_destinatario>*******</cep_destinatario>
      <codigo_usuario_postal />
      <centro_custo_cliente />
      <numero_nota_fiscal>0046287</numero_nota_fiscal>
      <serie_nota_fiscal>4</serie_nota_fiscal>
      <valor_nota_fiscal>6,72</valor_nota_fiscal>
      <natureza_nota_fiscal />
      <descricao_objeto />
      <valor_a_cobrar>0</valor_a_cobrar>
    </nacional>
    <servico_adicional>
      <codigo_servico_adicional>025</codigo_servico_adicional>
      <valor_declarado>0</valor_declarado>
    </servico_adicional>
    <dimensao_objeto>
      <tipo_objeto>002</tipo_objeto>
      <dimensao_altura>2</dimensao_altura>
      <dimensao_largura>11</dimensao_largura>
      <dimensao_comprimento>16</dimensao_comprimento>
      <dimensao_diametro>0</dimensao_diametro>
    </dimensao_objeto>
    <data_postagem_sara />
    <status_processamento>0</status_processamento>
    <numero_comprovante_postagem />
    <valor_cobrado />
  </objeto_postal>
  <objeto_postal>
    <numero_etiqueta>DW009688984BR</numero_etiqueta>
    <codigo_objeto_cliente />
    <codigo_servico_postagem>40096</codigo_servico_postagem>
    <cubagem>0</cubagem>
    <peso>5500</peso>
    <rt1 />
    <rt2 />
    <destinatario>
      <nome_destinatario>Fulano</nome_destinatario>
      <telefone_destinatario>11999999999</telefone_destinatario>
      <celular_destinatario>11999999999</celular_destinatario>
      <email_destinatario>fulano@mail.com.br</email_destinatario>
      <logradouro_destinatario>Endereco fulano</logradouro_destinatario>
      <complemento_destinatario />
      <numero_end_destinatario>3900</numero_end_destinatario>
    </destinatario>
    <nacional>
      <bairro_destinatario>BARRA DA TIJUCA</bairro_destinatario>
      <cidade_destinatario>RIO DE JANEIRO</cidade_destinatario>
      <uf_destinatario>RJ</uf_destinatario>
      <cep_destinatario>*******</cep_destinatario>
      <codigo_usuario_postal />
      <centro_custo_cliente />
      <numero_nota_fiscal>0046288</numero_nota_fiscal>
      <serie_nota_fiscal>4</serie_nota_fiscal>
      <valor_nota_fiscal>6,00</valor_nota_fiscal>
      <natureza_nota_fiscal />
      <descricao_objeto />
      <valor_a_cobrar>0</valor_a_cobrar>
    </nacional>
    <servico_adicional>
      <codigo_servico_adicional>025</codigo_servico_adicional>
      <valor_declarado>0</valor_declarado>
    </servico_adicional>
    <dimensao_objeto>
      <tipo_objeto>002</tipo_objeto>
      <dimensao_altura>2</dimensao_altura>
      <dimensao_largura>11</dimensao_largura>
      <dimensao_comprimento>16</dimensao_comprimento>
      <dimensao_diametro>0</dimensao_diametro>
    </dimensao_objeto>
    <data_postagem_sara />
    <status_processamento>0</status_processamento>
    <numero_comprovante_postagem />
    <valor_cobrado />
  </objeto_postal>
</correioslog>
```

Comment: Esse erro ocorre no sistema dos correios?

Comment: Já consegui resolver esse problema. Tive que tomar mais cuidado com caracteres especiais e alguns campos que não estavam contidos no xml.

Comment: Poderia considerar colocar uma resposta incluindo sua correção para ajudar futuros membros da comunidade que venham a ter um problema igual ou parecido.